# iFrame within an iFrame

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, webdriver

I have a program in which I am calling an iFrame within an iFrame however when I attempt to return to the first iFrame it can no longer find the elements.

I have tried both

```
base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PopUpCont");
    Add_Prefix_NewContact();
    Add_FirstName_NewContact();
    Add_MiddleName_NewContact();
    Add_LastName_NewContact();
    Add_Suffix_NewContact();
    iFrameConvertion_Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PrimaryAcctPick");
    Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
    Add_JobTitle_NewContact();
```

as well as

```
base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PopUpCont");
    Add_Prefix_NewContact();
    Add_FirstName_NewContact();
    Add_MiddleName_NewContact();
    Add_LastName_NewContact();
    Add_Suffix_NewContact();
    iFrameConvertion_Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PrimaryAcctPick");
    Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PopUpCont");
    Add_JobTitle_NewContact();
```

however neither solution can find the next web element, so I don't believe I am returning to the first iFrame correctly. I know the web element works as I have commented out and tried that as well.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like iframes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares to take a look I found the solution.

```
base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PopUpCont");
    Add_Prefix_NewContact();
    Add_FirstName_NewContact();
    Add_MiddleName_NewContact();
    Add_LastName_NewContact();
    Add_Suffix_NewContact();
    iFrameConvertion_Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().frame("PrimaryAcctPick");
    Add_PrimaryAcct_NewContact();
    base.getDriver().switchTo().parentFrame();
    Add_JobTitle_NewContact();
    Add_Email_NewContact();
```

Parent Frame got me back to where I needed.